# Manipulating data frame in R (aggregating by the player)

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, datatable

I have the csv file, which has the following format:

```
Player    Sports      Win     Loss
Brian     Football     5       3
Brian     Basketball   4       1
Brian     Bowling      7       0
Chris     Football     3       3
Chris     Basketball   3       4
. . . . 
. . . .
```

I would like to change the format to the following:

```
Name&Sports   Win         Loss    Total
Brian         16           4       20
Football      5            3       8
Basketball    4            1       5
Bowling       7            0       7
Chris         6            7       13
Football      3            3       6
Basketball    3            4       7   
. . . .
. . . .
```

Basically, in the new format, we first write the name of the person and the total number of wins, losses, games played across all sports that person played. In the following rows, we write each sports the person played, and total number of wins, losses, games played in that particular sports. Once we wrote everything for that person, we move on to the next person and do the same thing.

Is there an easy way of doing it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text = "Player    Sports      Win     Loss
Brian     Football     5       3
                 Brian     Basketball   4       1
                 Brian     Bowling      7       0
                 Chris     Football     3       3
                 Chris     Basketball   3       4",header=T)

tmp <- aggregate(df$Win,by=list(df$Player),sum)
tmp <- cbind(tmp, aggregate(df$Loss,by=list(df$Player),sum)[2])
names(tmp) <- colnames(df)[2:4]

df <- rbind(df[,2:ncol(df)], tmp)          
df$Total <- df$Loss + df$Win
df
```

> ```
>       Sports Win Loss Total
> 1   Football   5    3     8
> 2 Basketball   4    1     5
> 3    Bowling   7    0     7
> 4   Football   3    3     6
> 5 Basketball   3    4     7
> 6      Brian  16    4    20
> 7      Chris   6    7    13
> ```

Or, if matching the row order in your example is important:

```
df <- rbind(tmp[1,], df[1:3,2:ncol(df)], 
            tmp[2,], df[4:nrow(df),2:ncol(df)]) # could easily be made more programmatic          
df$Total <- df$Loss + df$Win
df
```

> ```
>        Sports Win Loss Total
> 1       Brian  16    4    20
> 2    Football   5    3     8
> 3  Basketball   4    1     5
> 4     Bowling   7    0     7
> 21      Chris   6    7    13
> 41   Football   3    3     6
> 5  Basketball   3    4     7
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A solution from `tidyverse`. `dt_final` is the final output.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Player    Sports      Win     Loss
Brian     Football     5       3
Brian     Basketball   4       1
Brian     Bowling      7       0
Chris     Football     3       3
Chris     Basketball   3       4",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Split data frame by players
dt_list <- split(dt, f = dt$Player)

# Define a funciton to process data
sum_fun <- function(dt){
  playername <- unique(dt$Player)

  dt1 <- dt %>% 
    mutate(Total = Win + Loss) %>%
    select(-Player) 
  dt2 <- data_frame(Sports = playername,
                    Win = sum(dt1$Win),
                    Loss = sum(dt1$Loss),
                    Total = sum(dt1$Total))
  dt3 <- bind_rows(dt2, dt1)

  return(dt3)
}

# Apply the function
dt_final <- dt_list %>%
  map_df(sum_fun) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  rename(`Name&Sports` = Sports)
```